# Making a custom class in c++ with constructor values

Tags: c++, function, class

I'm still learning c++ and have a lot more experience with Java. In Java, creating a class can be as simple as this:

```
public class vertex 
{

public double x, y, z;

 public boolean eliminated = true; 


 public vertex(double x, double y, double z)
 {
     //vertex constructor
 }

}
```

I'm trying to do something pretty much identical in C++, save for built in "get" functions for returning the values that should be set when creating an instance of the class, and want to know if my syntax is correct. Here is the class:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

class Vertex // Standard way of defining the class
{

public:
  // This means that all of the functions below this(and any variables) are accessible to the rest of the program.

    Vertex(double x, double y, double z);
    //constructor

    double getX();
    double getY();
    double getZ();

    double x;
    double y;
    double z;


};

double Vertex:: getX()
{
    return x;
}
```

I would also like advice on creating a class that has instances of custom classes like the one aboce within them.

Comment: If you're making all of the member variables public, why do you need get/set functions?

Comment: Have you tried *compiling* it? The compiler is very good at finding and reporting syntax errors.

Comment: Also, a class can be used very much like any other type, so if you know how to declare local variables of a class-type then you already know how to declare member variables.

Comment: The tail of your question "I would like advice on creating a class that has instances of custom classes like the one abo[v]e within them" is extremely vague. I would suggest you either remove it and ask that question separately, or expound on it with an example and show what your specific concerns are.

Comment: `double Vertex:: getX()` should be `double Vertex::getX()` and your includes are weird.

Comment: Well your get functions are not needed since all of your data members are public.

Comment: I suggest reading some c++ resources to learn the syntax. You might want to use member initialization list.

Comment: @Maria-Andersado What does `boolean` evaluate to in Java? I asked this because a true : false type in c++ is a `bool` and a `boolean` in c++ is a `typedef` to an `unsigned char`.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class vertex 
{
  public double x, y, z;
  public boolean eliminated = true; 
  public vertex(double x, double y, double z)
  {
     //vertex constructor
  }
}
```

To mimic this Java class as simply and as exactly as possible in C++ you would do this:

```
struct vertex{
   double x, y, z;
   bool eliminated = true;
   vertex(double x, double y, double z){
      //vertex constructor
   }
};
```

Remarkably similar right? Note that the `eliminated` member is default initiated, which is new to C++11, so make sure you have an up to date compiler.
`struct` is used instead of class because all of your members are public anyway. You could also use `class` and the `public:` access specifier.
You do not need access methods (getters) because everything is public already, as in your Java class.

You don't need any includes in for your vertex class definitions and you definitely should NOT put a `using` declaration any header files.

To mimic Java method parameter passing you pass copies for primitives and non-const pointers (not references) for object instance parameters.

edit - fixed the silly issues that I missed and that the human compilers below spotted :)

Comment: Should be bool instead of boolean. Also, default values for members appeared with C++11.

Comment: That will not compile; in VS you will get a compiler error C2628: (did you forget a ';'?)

Comment: @BenjaminBannier Thanks. I noticed that last night but for some reason the app doesn't work well with my google account, so had to wait til I was back at a PC.

Comment: @FrancisCugler I've appended that now. Thanks for the error check.

Answer (score -1):

This might help you out:

**Vector3.h**

```
#ifndef VECTOR3_H
#define VECTOR3_H

namespace myNamespace {  // Add This Because Many Libraries may define a Vector3 Object

class Vector3 {
    union {
        float m_f3[3];
        struct {
            float m_fx;
            float m_fy;
            float m_fz;
        };
    };

    inline Vector3();
    inline Vector3( float x, float y, float z );
    inline Vector3( float *pfv );
    ~Vector3();

    // Add Your inline overloaded operators & inline function declarations here.
};

#include "Vector3.inl"

} // namespace myNameSpace

#endif // VECTOR3_H
```

**Vector3.inl**

```
// ------------------------------------------------------
// Vector3() - Default Constructor Sets All Values To 0
inline Vector3::Vector3() :
m_fx( 0 ),
m_fy( 0 ),
m_fz( 0 ) {
} // Vector3

// ------------------------------------------------------
// Vector3() - Takes (x,y,z) Parameters
inline Vector3::Vector3( float x, float y, float z ) :
m_fx( x ),
m_fy( y ),
m_fz( z ) {
} // Vector3

// ------------------------------------------------------
// Vector3() - Takes A Pointer To Type
inline Vector3::Vector3( float *pfv ) :
m_fx( pfv[0] ),
m_fy( pfv[1] ),
m_fz( pfv[2] ) {
} // Vector3
```

**Vector3.cpp**

```
#include "Vector3.h"

namespace myNamespace { 

// ----------------------------------------------
// ~Vector3() - Default Destructor - Does Nothing
// Only Defined Here So That There Is Some Type Of Translation 
// Unit In The Object File Generated When Compiling
Vector3::~Vector3() {
} // ~Vector3

} // namespace myNamespace
```

To use this:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Vector3.h"

int main() {
    using namespace myNamespace; // Forgot to add this line here.

    Vector3 v1;

    std::cout << "Default Constructor Used: " << std::endl;
    std::cout << "v1 = ( " << v1.m_fx << ", "
                           << v1.m_fy << ", "
                           << v1.m_fz << " )" << std::endl;
    // Or This Way Works Too
    std::cout << "v1 = ( " << v1.m_f3[0] << ", "
                           << v1.m_f3[1] << ", "
                           << v1.m_f3[2] << " )" << std::endl;

    Vector3 v2( 2.2f, 3.3f. 4.4f );
    std::cout << "2nd Constructor Used: " << std::endl;
    std::cout << "v2 = ( " << v2.m_f3[0] << ", "
                           << v2.m_f3[1] << ", "
                           << v2.m_f3[2] << " )" << std::endl;


    float f3[3] = { 4.5f, 6.7f, 8.9f };
    Vector3 v3( f3 );
    std::cout << "3rd Constructor Used: " << std::endl;
    std::cout << "v3 = ( " << v3.m_fx << ", "
                           << v3.m_f3[1] << ", "
                           << v3.m_fz << " )" << std::endl;

} // main
```

**EDIT:**

If you want a have a class that includes instances of another user define class then it is as simple as this:

**SomeClass.h**

```
#ifndef SOME_CLASS_H
#define SOME_CLASS_H

namespace myNamespace {

class Vector3;

class SomeClass {
private:
    Vector3 m_currentPosition;
    Vector3 m_velocity;
    Vector3 m_finalPosition;

public:
     SomeClass( Vector3 initialPosition, Vector3 currentVelocity );

     Vector3 getFinalPosition() const;

private:
     void calculateFinalPosition();
};

} // namespace myNamespace
```

**SomeClass.cpp**

```
#include "SomeClass.h"
#include "Vector3.h"

namespace myNamespace {

SomeClass::SomeClass( Vector3 initialPosition, Vector3 currentVelocity ) :
m_currentPosition( initialPosition ),
m_velocity( currentVelocity ) {
    calculateFinalPosition();
}

Vector3 SomeClass::getFinalPosition() const {
    return m_finalPosition;
} // getFinalPosition

void SomeClass::calculateFinalPosition() {
   // Perform The Appropriate Calculation Here To Find The Final Position
} // calculateFinalPosition

} // namespace myNamespace
```

However for this to work; this would require the Vector3 to have the overloaded operators, functions such as cross, dot etc., to be defined.

Comment: I didn't down-vote you so I'm just guessing, but I would imagine that the reason is that the answer is very complex. That's not usually a problem, but given the obviously inexperienced OP I think that it might be in this case. Anyway, as I said that's just a guess.

Comment: Also I would probably discourage the use of a raw pointer. The OP is coming from Java where a syntax like `inline Vector3( float[] pfv );` would be more common. I would still encourage the use of `inline Vector3( const array<float, 3>& vectComponents);` instead. The OP should not need to worry about array-to-pointer decay, and the meaning of the `[]` operator.

Comment: @Dennis true; but even with the use of a raw pointer; the inline vector class does not use the heap so there is no need to worry about memory management in this context or introducing the possibility of memory leaks. The constructor takes a pointer to a type which allows the user or caller to pass an array. The constructor will only allow the first 3 indexed values to be used. I showed this be typically this a basic design of a Vector2, Vector3, Vector4 class that is used in many basic c++ math libraries. In graphics; a point or a vertex has the same implementation as a Vector.

Comment: Sure, but the caller could pass `nullptr` or a pointer to free memory... Anyway I'm just speculating. Whoever downvoted might have had a different problem altogether.